# GeoServer WMS service not visible when upgrading Java version

Tags: geoserver, java, azure

I am currently using Azure WebApp services to run my GeoServer application.
According to GeoServer's documentation the war file is compatible with Java 8 or 11.
I have been using Java 8 1.8.0_181, when I tried to upgrade this to Java 11 (any version available in Azure) as well as any Java 8 version greater than 1.8.0_181. The WMS layer preview does not display the sample services layers. Furthermore, I cannot get the WMS service to visually work at all.  Example URL: https://<WEBAPP_Deployed>.azurewebsites.net/geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=tiger%3Atiger_roads&bbox=-74.02722%2C40.684221%2C-73.907005%2C40.878178&width=476&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers

I have also tried to load the WMS sample service into QGIS. I am able to get capabilities (GC) but cannot get the visual data to load. The WMS GC file will download from the layer preview tab, but I cannot get the visual layer to show as the documentations state. I've also tried connect my PostgreSQL database to the GeoServer. Once again the WMS layers are not visible but the WFS service is.  I should note for all versions of Java, it appears the WFS layers work and are visible (although I did not confirm this with every version of Java I tried).

I thought it may have something to do with Tomcat; however, I was able to successfully upgraded my Tomcat to Tomcat 9 : webserver version 9.0.46 and the WMS works as long as I am using Java 8 1.8.0_181.  As soon as I upgrade the Java webserver version the WMS services stop working.

I would like to upgrade my Azure WebApp to Java 11 and continue to access WMS services.

&format=image/png does not work. That's how the WMS is called in QGIS. However, it will work if I use Java version 8 1.8.0_181 or below. When I try to use a &format-image/png call I get a timeout in QGIS & 500 http error.

When I open the wms that downloads from GeoServer's Layer preview; I receive the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. 
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException> java.lang.StackOverflowError </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I wonder if there is a way to compare the java 11 found in azure to the normal java??

I also set the logging to developer geoserver and then upgraded my Java from 1.8.0_181 to Java 11 11.0.1_11 there's absolutely no logging errors or anything when I try to view the layer preview for open layers. The WMS downloads and provides the same error as provided above. No additional logging details to share.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Does GetMap with `&format=image/png`work?

Comment: GeoServer definitely works on Java 11 as well as latest Java 8, but I have no idea what versions of Java are available on Azure, and if/how they differ from others. Can you elaborate. Also, check the logs, do you see any stack trace in there, when you make GetMap requests? If so, please report.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.